# Convert RSS pubDate to a timestamp

Tags: php, rss, timestamp, pubdate

How to convert a date string `Mon, 24 May 2010 17:54:00 GMT` from RSS feed to a timestamp in PHP ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `strtotime()`. It takes a date string as its first argument and returns a Unix timestamp.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: It looks like strtotime give strange results when the string contains the timezone. For example with "Sat, 21 Sep 2010 00:00 GMT" I get 1285372800 (25-09-2010)

Answer (score 14):

Try This:

```
$pubDate = $item->pubDate;
$pubDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime($pubDate));
```

Answer (score 7):

`strtotime` does not work with different timezones.

I have just written this function to convert RSS pubDates to timestamps which does take into account the different timezones:

```
function rsstotime($rss_time) {
    $day       = substr($rss_time, 5, 2);
    $month     = substr($rss_time, 8, 3);
    $month     = date('m', strtotime("$month 1 2011"));
    $year      = substr($rss_time, 12, 4);
    $hour      = substr($rss_time, 17, 2);
    $min       = substr($rss_time, 20, 2);
    $second    = substr($rss_time, 23, 2);
    $timezone  = substr($rss_time, 26);

    $timestamp = mktime($hour, $min, $second, $month, $day, $year);

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    if(is_numeric($timezone)) {
        $hours_mod    = $mins_mod = 0;
        $modifier     = substr($timezone, 0, 1);
        $hours_mod    = (int) substr($timezone, 1, 2);
        $mins_mod     = (int) substr($timezone, 3, 2);
        $hour_label   = $hours_mod > 1 ? 'hours' : 'hour';
        $strtotimearg = $modifier . $hours_mod . ' ' . $hour_label;
        if($mins_mod) {
            $mins_label = $mins_mod > 1 ? 'minutes' : 'minute';
            $strtotimearg .= ' ' . $mins_mod . ' ' . $mins_label;
        }
        $timestamp = strtotime($strtotimearg, $timestamp);
    }

    return $timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?
    `date_create_from_format(DateTime::RSS, $item->pubDate);`

I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The rsstotime() function did not work properly if the pubDate in rss feed had timezone other than **+0000**. The problem was with the $modifier, it had to be reversed. To fix that two lines had to be added, so the line:

```
$modifier = substr($timezone, 0, 1);
```

became:

```
$modifier = substr($timezone, 0, 1);        
if($modifier == "+"){ $modifier = "-"; } else
if($modifier == "-"){ $modifier = "+"; }
```

Just to clarify the modification - for example if the **pubDate** was **Wed, 22 May 2013 17:09:36 +0200** then the row

```
$timestamp = strtotime($strtotimearg, $timestamp
```

offsetted the time by two hours not resetted it to **+0000** timezone as expected.

The **Wed, 22 May 2013 17:09:36 +0200** shows that the time presented here is in the timezone GMT +2.

The code did not work properly and added extra two hours to the time, so the time became **Wed, 22 May 2013 19:09:36 +0000**, instead **Wed, 22 May 2013 15:09:36 +0000** as it should have been.

Answer (score -3):

```
function pubdatetotime($pubDate) {

$months = array('Jan' => '01', 'Feb' => '02', 'Mar' => '03', 
'Apr' => '04', 'May' => '05', 'Jun' => '06', 
'Jul' => '07', 'Aug' => '08', 'Sep' => '09', 
'Oct' => '10', 'Nov' => '11', 'Dec' => '12');

$date = substr($pubDate, 5,11);
$year = substr($date, 7,4); 
$month = substr($date, 3,3);
$d =  substr($date, 0,2);

$time = substr($pubDate, 17,8);

return $year."-".$months[$month]."-".$d." ".$time;  
}
```

Try this function