# What is the best way to parse a RSS pubDate in PHP?

Tags: php, date, rss

I get a RSS and I manage it with PHP: I parse it, and I get the date value with :

```
$data_feed=$item[pubdate];
```

If I print this date, I get for example :

```
Wed, 05 Oct 2011 00:00:00 PST
```

I know that on RSS there are many date format, such as PST, EST, GMT, +0200 and son on.

How can I Parse on PHP any kind of date format from a RSS? As example, I'd like to have always the format DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: What about `strtotime` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert RSS pubDate to a timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912262/convert-rss-pubdate-to-a-timestamp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will handle most [common formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

From there, you can use [`strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to display the format you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

This simple command works for me:

```
$date = date_create_from_format(DateTime::RSS, $string);
```

Comment: best answer ever!!

Comment: this looks good, but failed for me in dates that include timezone info, such as `Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00+0200`

Comment: @oelna it seems you don't have the space before the timezone as RSS format expects. Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php and select/create the format that matches you case.